# Getting Error "Delegate 'System.Func<EntityType,int,bool> does not take 1 arguments" from Entity Framework LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to do a very stupidly basic LINQ query on my Entity Framework context. It goes something like this:

```cs
var query = from e in context.Entity1s.Include("Entity2")
            where e.Id == someVar.E1Id
            select e;
```

As you can see, a stupidly basic, practically copy-paste-out-of-the-textbook query. But Visual Studio puts a red squiggly underline on the 'where' keyword, and I get a build error that looks like:

> Delegate '`System.Func<Entity1, int, bool>`' does not take 1 arguments

I can't make heads or tails of it. Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: Have you looked at the method signature for `Include`? I've never used EF, but that looks like it would give away the error pretty quickly, either in its return value or, more likely, its parameters.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I have. It takes 1 arg of type `string`. Again, I am also using this as demonstrated right out of some course material, and I have also used it before successfully. Furthermore, I would expect Visual Studio to put its cantankerous red squiggly line under `context.Entity1s.Include("Entity2")`, not the `where`, and complain specifically about how I was calling `DbQuery<TResult>.Include(string path)` if that were the problem.

Comment: What type is e.Id and what is someVar.E1Id?  I am hoping they are both int.

Comment: @MobyDisk Yes, they are both one of short, int, or long (both the same one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much semi-random tinkering, I fixed this problem. I'm not sure why I had to do this now, when I've never had to before, and I'm not completely sure why on earth this fixed it, or how the heck it has anything to do with the error I was getting, but I solved it like this:

```
//          --->Added This<--
var query = from Entity1 e in context.Entity1s.Include("Entity2")
           where e.Id == someVar.E1Id
          select e;
```

Turned `e` into a strongly declared type instead of making Visual Studio deduce its type at compile time like I should be able to. Oh well. Not a big deal. No reason I would ever NOT be able to declare e's type.

Still it IRRITATES the HECK out of me that I didn't really solve this. I mean, I got it to work, but WHY? Why did what I do make a difference? Especially when it never used to matter?

I'll choose my answer here as the correct one, since it solves the issue, but if anyone has information to expound on the "why it worked" aspect, please leave comments. I'm sure I'm not the only person who would love to learn more.

Comment: Fascinating.  Wacky.  I have an idea: Suppose you undo your fix and remove the "where e.Id == someVar1.E1Id" from the query.  Then it should compile.  You could then run it in the debugger, and see what type it thinks e is.